# Deploy wp8 application on a wp7 smartphone

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a windows smartphone , version 7.10. can i deploy it for applications developed with the wp8 sdk and will these applications work without any problems on wp8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WP 8 and windows 8 will share common core, I think that we can say that such deployment will be possible with maybe minor tweaks regarding device resolution. Maybe you can think that you can use snapped view on tablet as a UI for phone.

It's not clear why you are referring to WP7, but **Windows Phone 8 apps will not run on any Windows Phone 7.x device**.

> The biggest thing today is that Windows Phone 8 has a shared common
>   core with Windows 8," said Windows Phone Manager Joe Belfiore at the
>   Windows Phone Summit in San Francisco, which was webcast. "For us,
>   this is a huge release and a huge year.

Comment: well i sent a request to get the wp8 sdk but i still have a wp 7.10, so i'm wondering if i can deploy applications on it? !

Comment: Also, Windows 8 apps will require from some, to a lot, of modifications to run on Windows Phone 8.